# Find a minimal natural number

Tags: number-theory

How can I find a minimal natural number that begins (in the decimal system) with $2016$ and which can be divided by $2017$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that there must be an answer of the form `2016xxxx` because the 10,000 consecutive numbers of this form are enough that there are several multiples of $2017$ among them.

We can also see that `2016xxx`, `2016xx`, or `2016x` won't work, because each of these gives a range of *fewer than* 2017 numbers that end *just before* a multiple of $2017$.

Finding the first solution of the form `2016xxxx` is just a matter of rounding $20{,}160{,}000$ up to the next multiple of $2017$:
$$ 2017 \times \left\lceil\frac{20160000}{2017}\right\rceil = 20161932 $$

Answer (score 3):

It must start with the numbers $2016...$, so it must be of the form $$2016 \times 10^{n}+m $$

Where $m<10^{n}$. Now note $$2016 \times 10^{n}+m \equiv -10^{n}+m \equiv 0 \pmod {2017}$$
 So, we have that $10^{n}-m$ must be a positive multiple of $2017$.

So $10^{n}-m=2017 \times 4$ is the method to minimize the integer. We get $n=4, m=1932$ The number is $$20161932$$

Comment: I get 20161932.

Comment: How did you get it? How do you get the exact values of n and m?

Comment: Why not $m=1932$? $20161932=2017\cdot9996$.

Comment: @robjohn can you share an answer?

Comment: This answer is trivially incorrect because you can substract $2017$ to that number and still have a number in the form $2016xyzw$ and divisible by $2017$

Comment: @Giulio Sorry, I will rectify my answer accordingly.

Comment: @robjohn I edited my answer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I edited my answer.

Comment: @Peter I edited the answer.

Comment: @idliketodothis Sorry for my previously incorrect answer.

Comment: The first equivalence is modulo 2017, right?

Comment: @idliketodothis Yes. That is true. That's why it's written $\pmod {2017}$.

Comment: It isn't.
I am talking about that one:
 2016×10n+m≡−10n

Comment: @idliketodothis Ohk. Fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

I computed
$2017-\bmod(20160,2017)=10$,
$2017-\bmod(201600,2017)=100$,
$2017-\bmod(2016000,2017)=1000$,
$2017-\bmod(20160000,2017)=1932$.

Therefore, I get
$$
20161932=2017\cdot9996
$$